# Error converting to PDF: The document has no pages at document.close()

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, exception, itext

The below code that I am using for convert the panel of the data to PDF.But it is giving an error:

> The document has no pages at the place of document.close()

Here is my code:

```
protected void ConvertPDF_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=test.pdf";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "7pt");
    htextw.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black");

    Panel1.RenderControl(htextw);//Name of the Panel
    Document document = new Document();
    document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 15, 5);
    FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 50, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();

    StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
    HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlworker.Parse(str);

    document.Close();
    Response.Write(document);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`htmlworker.Parse` method gives you the parsed elements. It parses the html elements and converts them to their iTextSharp equivalent elements. Now you should add them to the document.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see what's in your `Panel` server control, but your code looks OK. And if the Panel only contains simple HTML, you don't necessarily need to add HTML `IElement` objects individually (when calling `HTMLWorker.ParseToList()`) to the `Document` object as suggested by @VahidN. Here's a simple example - `.aspx` file:

```
<%@ Page Language='C#' AutoEventWireup='true' CodeFile='panelTest.aspx.cs' Inherits='panelTest' %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head runat='server'><title></title></head>
<body><form id='form1' runat='server'>
<asp:Panel ID='testPanel' runat='server'>
<h1>A H1 Heading</h1>
<table width='100%' border='1' align='center' 
  cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' 
>
<tr><td>TABLE ROW 1: CELL 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>TABLE ROW 2: CELL 1</td></tr>
</table>
<p>A Paragraph with <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em> text.</p>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button runat='server'
  oncommand='process'
  text='Convert HtmlControl to PDF'
/>
</form></body></html>
```

Code-behind file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

public partial class panelTest : Page {
  protected void process(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=test.pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);    
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    htmlWriter.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "10pt");
    htmlWriter.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black");      
    testPanel.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    using (Document document = new Document()) {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
      document.Open();
      StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(stringWriter.ToString());
      HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
      htmlworker.Parse(stringReader);    
    }
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

With that being said - if the Panel contains child controls or complex HTML (images for example), you will have problems. You need to take into account that HTMLWorker is a **very** simple parser.